# Run bash script when SVN remote files have changed

Tags: bash, svn, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to create a Bask script on Ubuntu server that should check if files where changed on a remote SVN repository. If so it should perform some tasks.
In  my case run doxygen and regenerate the documentation.

I'm having trouble interpreting the svn status response.
I've been looking all week and tried several suggestion found but it is still not working. To be precise the tasks are always run no matter if their are changed files.

Here's my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the status:
svnstatus=$(svn status -u -q)

#Check for modified or new files:
#This part is not working correctly
added=$(printf "%s" "$svnstatus" | sed -n 's/[Added] *\(.*\)/\1/p')
modified=$(printf "%s" "$svnstatus" | sed -n 's/[Updated] *\(.*\)/\1/p')

if [ "x$added" != "x" -o "x$modified" != "x" ]
then
  svn update
  echo regenerated documentation using doxygen    
fi
```

The main issue is with the sed part. I'm new to Ubuntu and that part is difficult for me. I copied that from a script I found on the Internet.

$svnstatus is

```
Status against revision: 75016
```

when nothing new and

```
    *    75016   Resources/graphs/dot_tags.txt
Status against revision:  75017
```

when a file is changed.

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Does `svn update` return success when it does something and failure otherwise? Can you get it to do that? Is the doxygen process run through make? If it is then just running make it likely not a big deal since it will avoid doing any work when nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sed command doesn't match the output `svn status -u -q` so it won't be doing anything useful.

Instead, you can use `grep` to check if there are any lines in the output with a `*` character in the 9th column, indicating a modified file.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the status:
svnstatus=$(svn status -u -q)

# Check for modified or new files:
if echo "$svnstatus" | grep -q '^........\*'
then
  svn update
  echo regenerated documentation using doxygen    
fi
```